# How do I set spelling and spelling highlight for markdown files?

Tags: autocmd, spelling

When I do this:

```
:set spell spelllang=en_us
:hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

It underlines the spell on markdown. I just need this auto command on markdown files.

If I put these commands in my .vimrc, and reopen a new vim with a README.md it doesn't underline the misspelled word.

How do I automatically underline bad spells on `.md` files. I use gruvbox colorscheme if that's any relevant. But I want a simple generic answer to apply to everything.

Comment: Try an ftplugin: put the command in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`

Comment: I tried ftplugin, spell checking is enabled but it still doesn't underline automatically, unless I explicitly type the `hi` command for the buffer.

Comment: Are you putting it in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` and not `~/.vim/ftplugin`? It's possible a color scheme is clearing the highlight group.

Comment: It picks up the first command, because spell check is enabled, but the second is possible to be cleared by gruvbox, I don't know what to do.

Comment: My usual advice for customizing a colorscheme (remembering that they apply globally, AFAIK) is to use something like `autocmd Colorscheme * highlight SpellBad cterm=underline` (replace the `*` if you want to be more specific, and as always wrap in an `augroup`)

Comment: Thanks, can you wrap that in a detailed answer, I don't understand very much\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting it in an ftplugin; putting the command in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim` will define your highlight group after the color scheme is loaded on startup.

However, this may break when changing color schemes because color schemes will typically call `:highlight clear` to clear any previously defined highlight groups before defining their own. This can cause user highlight groups defined in `.vimrc` to be overridden.

To remedy this, you can create an autocommand that will execute a command every time a color scheme is loaded, but you'll need to check the `filetype` of the current buffer.

So, replace

```
set spelllang=en_us
hi SpellBad cterm=underline
```

in your `.vimrc` with

```
augroup UnderlineSpell
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * if &ft ==? 'markdown' 
                          \| highlight SpellBad cterm=underline
                          \| set spelllang=en_us
                       \| endif
augroup END
```

It's important to wrap the autocommand in an `augroup` to prevent defining the autocommand more than once (if you were to change color schemes, for example). `autocmd!` is used to clear any existing autocommands defined for the current `augroup`.

There's also a [very informative GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f) about overriding color schemes in this way that would be a good read.

---

Also see the following help pages:

- **vim startup**

  - [`:h vimfiles`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#vimfiles)
  - [`:h after-directory`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#after%2Ddirectory)
- **autocommands**

  - [`:h :autocmd`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aautocmd)
  - [`:h autocommand-events`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#autocommand%2Devents)
  - [`:h ColorScheme`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme)
  - [`:h :augroup`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#%3Aaugroup)
- **highlight and spelling**

  - [`:h :highlight`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight)
  - [`:h 'spelllang'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27spelllang%27)

Comment: The second `autocmd` should not need a `!`; I'm not sure if it will break anything, but it's definitely not necessary (and might well be wrong). Anyway, you missed the spelling settings; you could [edit] and fold in my comments about `ftplugin`s and I won't mind

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks, I've incorporated your suggestions :)